# Override method implemented in anonymous class not recognized

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, as taken from this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

```
        final TextView mResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://www.example.com/";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        mResponse.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mResponse.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });
```

However, despite the implementation of the onResponse() method within the anonymous Listener class, Response.Listener is being underlined in red, giving the following error: "'Anonymous class derived from Listener' must either be either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onResponse(T)' in 'Listener'". I'm not exactly sure why it isn't seeing that I've done exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response.Listener is a generic type. You have to specify:

```
new Response.Listener<String>()
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks! The issue I have now, though is: how do I save the returned `response` string to a variable I can use in the program? inner classes apparently require the variables they accessed to be declared `final`, which prevents me from saving the value of `response` to a pre-declared string...

Comment: You will not be able to assign new value to a final String so either create a class for Listener with a field response or set the response exactly as in the code in your question. Please note the meaning of final keyword in Java - you declare final TextView mResponse so you cannot reassign the reference but you can call setters.

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

This problem comes when you use two libraries. To solve the problem, just remove

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Your code will work fine.